# How UUID:: randomUUID interpreted?

Tags: java, java-8

I know that in Java 8 , (String[]::new) is interpreted as  : size-> new String[].

I am eager to know how (UUID :: randomUUID) is interpreted?
It is used as Stream.generate(UUID :: randomUUID). But, I wanna know, what exactly is meant by UUID :: randomUUID

How generator function acts here?

Comment: [`() -> UUID.randomUUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID--)

Comment: `String[]::new` is rather equivalent to `size-> new String[size]`

Answer (score 1):

UUID::randomUUID is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to the [randomUUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) method on UUID.

[Generate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) accepts a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), and UUID.randomUUID fufills that [Functional Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

In short, String[]::new may have special behavior, but arrays are an exception, not the normal rule, and I hadn't actually previously thought about the size needing to be defined.